# Multiple screens/resolutions/images

Tags: resolution, screens

I need to create images for a slideshow. The problem is that the images will be displayed in different screens. 
I want to know if I can use the same resolution for all of them (1920 x 1080) 72px/inch.

Screens:
1. 24ft x 14ft pitch 12mm - Aspect ration must be 16:9
2. 12ft x 9ft pitch 15mm - Aspect ration must be 16:9
3. 55" TV - Supports full HD (1080 or 720)
4. 42" TV - Supports full HD (1080 or 720)
5. 19" screen - Maximum resolution is 1440 x 900

I don't know much about resolutions and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How does this relate to software development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1920x1080 will be large enough for any television. Full HD (1080p) means 1080 horizontal scanlines (meaning 1080 pixels tall).

The size in inches is irrelevant in this case.

The only reason I could see for going larger than 1920x1080 is if the screen depth is more than 72 DPI (e.g. the iPhone retina display, which is 326 ppi)

Comment: But, what about the big screens ( 24ft x 14ft pitch 12mm ) do they still use the same kind of resolution?

Comment: Yes, they would still use one of the popular resolutions (1080, 720) if made in the last 5-10 years. Unless they are high resolution projection (think movie theater quality), the best resolution consumer TVs would be 1080px tall. Sony and other manufacturers are just now starting to produce high resolution displays for home use.